# Jupyter Notebook: A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The last months Python ran without any problems.

Today I executed the following code to install tensorflowjs:

```
!pip install tb-nightly
!pip install gast==0.2.2
!pip install --user tensorflowjs
```

After this, I tried to load a model with that code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("path\to\model\*.hdf5")
```

It did not work and I got this error code but that is not the actual question. But maybe you get a better impression of the problem.

```
ValueError: Expected a Trackable object for export, got <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f33a5a716a0>.
```

Now, when I try to run any Jupyter Notebook I get this error:

```
Connection failed
A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.
```

I don't know why. Maybe it is because of the operations I executed to get to run tensorflowjs but I do not have any explanation. Is there someone who can help?

Thanks a lot in advanvce!

Comment: I solved the issue by generating a new python environment.